# Substituting variables in an equation

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I wanted to see what would happen if I took

```
    (E^(-3 (1 + d) t) (1 + 3 d + 2 E^(3 (1 + d) t) - 
   E^((-3 - d) t + 3 (1 + d) t) - 3 d E^((-3 - d) t + 3 (1 + d) t) + 
   6 E^((-3 - d) t + 3 (1 + d) t) C[1] + 
   6 d E^((-3 - d) t + 3 (1 + d) t) C[1]))/(6 (1 + d))
```

And substituted

```
1/(3 + 3 d) + C[1]
```

for some arbitrary variable w

So I wrote:

```
(E^(-3 (1 + d) t) (1 + 3 d + 2 E^(3 (1 + d) t) - 
E^((-3 - d) t + 3 (1 + d) t) - 3 d E^((-3 - d) t + 3 (1 + d) t) + 
6 E^((-3 - d) t + 3 (1 + d) t) C[1] + 
6 d E^((-3 - d) t + 3 (1 + d) t) C[1]))/(6 (1 + d)) /. 
 1/(3 + 3 d) + C[1] -> w
```

And I got the same output as input:

[image]

So I am wondering how to substitute out the C1s and replace them with w. Thank you for your help.

Comment: it works for me.  Did you try with clean kernel?   ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DrDWt.png)

Comment: Yes, I've added a picture.

Comment: So ClearAll[t,d] didn't work, but ClearAll[t,d,x,y,w] did. However, all it did was to give me the initial expression with no modifications. I want to get rid of the C1s and to put in w. How do I make mathematics do this? I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: `I want to get rid of the C1s and to put in w`  then just do  `stuff /. C[1] -> w`

Comment: What I meant was: I want to get rid of the C1s in such a way that  1/(3 + 3 d) + C[1] -> w . So there are no C1s remaining but w is in the expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the objective is to replace the `C[1]`, write your replacement that way.

```
expr /. C[1] -> w - 1/(3 + 3 d) // Simplify
(* 
  (1 + 2*E^(3*(1 + d)*t) + E^(2*d*t)*(-3 + 6*w) + d*(3 + E^(2*d*t)*(-3 + 6*w)))/
  (E^(3*(1 + d)*t)*(6*(1 + d)))
*)
```

The pattern to the left of `->` must match the `FullForm` of the subexpression you're attempting to rewrite, and for a complicated subexpression, that's tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Does this produce the result you are looking for?

```
(E^(-3 (1 + d) t) (1 + 3 d + 2 E^(3 (1 + d) t) - 
      E^((-3 - d) t + 3 (1 + d) t) - 
      3 d E^((-3 - d) t + 3 (1 + d) t) + 
      6 E^((-3 - d) t + 3 (1 + d) t) C[1] + 
      6 d E^((-3 - d) t + 3 (1 + d) t) C[1]))/(6 (1 + d)) /. C[1] -> w
```